# Jersey2 client list mapping

Tags: java, json, jackson, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I'm trying to develop a rest client using Jersey and the jackson mapper for the object mappings. I'm receiving the following json response:

```
{
    "currentPage": 0,
    "pageSize": 15,
    "totalResults": 1,
    "sortDirection": "",
    "orderBy": "",
    "data": [
        [
            1,
            "ingredient",
            3,
            "former",
            4,
            "nestle",
            5,
            "fish",
            true
        ]
    ]
}
```

So the issue comes when I try to map the service response, I'm getting all the values but the "data" field, which comes as null. This is the code chunk where I'm doing the call:

```
public PageDTO<IngredienteBusquedaDTO> findIngredientesPaged(final IngredienteBusquedaCriteria criteria,
        final String token) {

    Client sslClient = null;
    try {
        sslClient = new SSLJerseyClient().getClient();

    } catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sslClient
            .register(JacksonFeature.class)
            .target("https://192.168.11.6:8442/servicios/ws/")
            .path("ingrediente/paged")
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .header("Authorization", token)
            .post(Entity.entity(criteria, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .readEntity(new GenericType<PageDTO<IngredienteBusquedaDTO>>() {
            });
}
```

The PageDTO class is parametrizable:

```
@Produces("application/json")
@JsonAutoDetect
public class PageDTO<T> implements Serializable {

    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5491202093571112081L;

    /** The current page. */
    private Integer currentPage;

    /** The page size. */
    private Integer pageSize;

    /** The total results. */
    private Integer totalResults;

    /** The sort direction. */
    private String sortDirection;

    /** The order by. */
    private String orderBy;

    /** The data. */
    @JsonProperty
    private List<T> data;

getters and setters...
```

And the IngredienteBusquedaDTO is an exact copy of the object being send from the service:

```
public class IngredienteBusquedaDTO implements Serializable {

    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7827829548387723259L;

    /** The id ingrediente. */
    private Long idIngrediente;

    /** The descripcion. */
    private String descripcion;

    /** The id proveedor. */
    private Long idProveedor;

    /** The descripcion proveedor. */
    private String descripcionProveedor;

    /** The id tipo ingrediente. */
    private Short idTipoIngrediente;

    /** The descripcion tipo ingrediente. */
    private String descripcionTipoIngrediente;

    /** The salsa. */
    private boolean salsa;

getters and setters
```

Any ideas of what's going on? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Data contains a list of lists. Your model only accepts data to be a single list. I hope this helps.

Comment: You might have to define it as `private List<IngredienteBusquedaDTO> data;`

Comment: Thanks @VincentBeltman I guess I must change something on the service to get a response like this:

{
    "currentPage": 0,
    "pageSize": 15,
    "totalResults": 1,
    "sortDirection": "",
    "orderBy": "",
    "data": [
        {
            "idIngrediente" : 1,
            "descripcion" : ingredient",
            "idProveedor" : 3,
            "descripcionProveedor" : "former",
            "id" : 4,
            "text" : "nestle",
            "idTipoIngrediente" : 5,
            "descripcionTipoIngrediente" : fish",
            "salsa" : true
        }
    ]
}